# File declaration in Java

Tags: java

If I just declare as

```
File file = new File("/opt/app/myfile.txt");
```

Does it open file? should I required to close it?
Please suggest me on this.

Comment: No. And no. It's an abstract representation of a `File` path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it open file ? No

Should I close it ? No

**The File only gives you access to the file and file system meta data. If you need to read or write the content of files, you should do so using either FileInputStream, FileOutputStream or RandomAccessFile.**

The File class in the Java IO API gives you access to the underlying file system. Using the File class you can:

- Check if a file or directory exists.
- Create a directory if it does not exist.
- Read the length of a file.
- Rename or move a file.
- Delete a file.
- Check if path is file or directory.
- Read list of files in a directory.

**If you are using Java NIO you will have to use the java.nio.FileChannel class instead (you can use both, but in case you want a pure Java NIO solution).**

Usage examples are as shown below

Check if File Exists

```
File file = new File("c:\\data\\input-file.txt");

boolean fileExists = file.exists();
```

Create a Directory if it Does Not Exist

```
File file = new File("c:\\users\\jakobjenkov\\newdir");

boolean dirCreated = file.mkdir();
```

File Length

```
File file = new File("c:\\data\\input-file.txt");

long length = file.length();
```

Rename or Move File

```
File file = new File("c:\\data\\input-file.txt");

boolean success = file.renameTo(new File("c:\\data\\new-file.txt"));
```

Delete File

```
File file = new File("c:\\data\\input-file.txt");

boolean success = file.delete();
```

Check if Path is File or Directory

```
File file = new File("c:\\data");

boolean isDirectory = file.isDirectory();
```

Read List of Files in Directory

```
File file = new File("c:\\data");

String[] fileNames = file.list();

File[]   files = file.listFiles();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is clear from [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29),

> Creates a new `File` instance by converting the given
>   pathname string into an abstract pathname.  If the given string is
>   the empty string, then the result is the empty abstract pathname.
>          @param   pathname  A pathname string    @throws  NullPointerException    If the `pathname` argument is
>   `null`

```
public File(String pathname) {
    if (pathname == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    this.path = fs.normalize(pathname);
    this.prefixLength = fs.prefixLength(this.path);
}
```